# Unable to delete private subkeys in GnuPG if no master key present

Tags: linux, command-line, gnupg, pgp

I have a GnuPG key pair with a master key (only *Certify* capability) and 3 subkeys (*Sign*, *Encrypt* and *Authenticate* capabilities respectively). Actually, when I start, I only have the private keys of the subkeys (I have a stub, marked with `#`, instead of the master private key)

I do as follows:

1. I list private keys (`gpg --list-secret-keys`). There is a master key stub (`#`) an three subkeys.
2. I encrypt a message with public *Encrypt* subkey (`gpg -e USER`)
3. I decrypt the message (`gpg -d`): Ok.
4. I delete de the three subkeys (`gpg --edit-key`). `gpg --delete-secret-keys` does not work on master key (it's only a stub) nor on the subkeys.
5. I delete the public master key (`gpg --delete-keys`)
6. I try to decrypt message from step 2: Not able, no private keys, Ok. I list private keys with `gpg --list-secret-keys`: No keys
7. I kill gpg-agent (`killall gpg-agent`)
8. I import **public** keys from key server again (`gpg --receive-keys`)
9. I try to decrypt message from step 2 and surprisingly I am able to decrypt it by introducing the passphrase that protects the private subkeys! The private keys are there if I execute `gpg --list-secret-keys` again.

I guess I didn't delete correctly the private subkeys, I guess with the `gpg --edit-key` command I only deleted the public subkeys. Buy how can I delete the private subkeys if no master key is present (it's only a stub)?

After importing the secret master key again, I'm able to delete the master private key and his three subkeys by executing `gpg --delete-secret-key`. Is this the only option I have? Isn't it possible to delete secret subkeys if the master key is only a stub?

Answer (score 6):

For GnuPG 2.1+, secret keys are stored in gpg-agent and only referenced by the main keyring.

Re-import the public subkeys again, then run `gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip`. This will show the 'fingerprint' of the raw asymmetric key belonging to each subkey (do not confuse this with the fingerprint of the whole PGP subkey with metadata and all).

For each subkey that you want to delete, run:

```
gpg-connect-agent "delete_key <keygrip>" /bye
```

Comment: Had the same problem. It worked.